# How do we get VSCode with XDebug to ignore known code issues?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, wordpress-plugin-creation

Environment : Visual Studio Code, PHP 7.4, XDebug, WordPress site in Local by Flywheel, all on Windows 10. This is all working. The issue us that there is a trivial unhandled exception that always occurs in WordPress which is ignored in normal processing. But the exception reports clutter my plugin debugging. So I'd like to eliminate XDebug reporting of just one small section of WP core code.

In index.php I've added the following to no effect:

```php
xdebug_set_filter(
    XDEBUG_FILTER_STACK,
    XDEBUG_PATH_INCLUDE,
    [__DIR__ . "/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/"]
);
```

I added similar code to wp-load.php, also no effect:

```php
$path=__DIR__ . "\\wp-content\\plugins\\myplugin";
xdebug_set_filter(
    XDEBUG_FILTER_STACK,
    XDEBUG_PATH_INCLUDE,
    [$path]
);
```

The $path is correct.

In the WP Core code (wp-db.php) I have bracketed the exception-throwing code with this:

```php
xdebug_disable(); ... xdebug_enable();
```

One thing that's confusing about this is that the VS Code intellisense doesn't recognize the xdebug functions, and yet using xdebug_break(); does cause XDebug to break.

- **Question 1: What do we do to get VSCode/PHP/Intelephense to recognize XDebug functions?**

Yes, the UI shows error "Call to undefined function xdebug_disable()". So in addition to just getting IDE support:

- **Question 2: What do we do to get a VSCode project/workspace to recognize the php_xdebug.dll features?**

(More specifically for this environment this is "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Local\lightning-services\php-7.4.1+16\bin\win64\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll")

For this specific challenge:

- **Question 3: What is the proper technique to get XDebug to avoid a specific code block?**

Do we bracket with enable/disable?
Do we use `xdebug_set_filter` to focus on just the namespace or folders of interest?
Do we bracket with something like this? :

```php
xdebug_start_error_collection();
...
xdebug_stop_error_collection();
xdebug_get_collected_errors(true);
```

Finally, because I want to learn how this works and not just get answers for this specific challenge:

- **Question 4: Where can we find documentation about how to use these functions to solve actual problems, outside of the great syntax docs provided at https://xdebug.org/docs/develop ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your questions seem to come from knowing about Xdebug 2, but using Xdebug 3 which has a changed set of configuration settings and functions, which are documented in the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).

> Question 1: Call to undefined function xdebug_disable()

This is because Xdebug 3 does no longer have this function, see: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#Changes-to-Functions

> Question 2: What do we do to get a VSCode project/workspace to recognize the php_xdebug.dll features?

It already does, because `xdebug_break()` works for you. You're just using functions of the old version.

> Question 3: What is the proper technique to get XDebug to avoid a specific code block?

Xdebug can't do that for debugging. It's usually built-into IDEs. PhpStorm for example has a way to exclude directories. I am not 100% about the VS Code Plugin, but they've recently made a change to not have [default exception filters](https://damjan.cvetko.org/blog/2021-06-06-vscode-php-debug-release-may-2021/#default-exception-filters) on by default, which might as well solve your problem.

> Do we bracket with enable/disable?

No. That function no longer exists, but it's only effect was showing, or not showing Xdebug's orange errors. It never had any effect on debugging.

> Do we use xdebug_set_filter to focus on just the namespace or folders of interest?

The filter has two categories, one for stack traces (with `XDEBUG_FILTER_STACK`) and one for code coverage (with `XDEBUG_FILTER_COVERAGE`). There is none for debugging yet, bug I've created a [feature request](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1985) to get this supported (from Xdebug 3.1).

> Do we bracket with something like this? :
>
> ```
> xdebug_start_error_collection();
> ...
> xdebug_stop_error_collection();
> xdebug_get_collected_errors(true);
> ```

That's only for collecting errors. It doesn't *stop* errors from occurring.

> Question 4: Where can we find documentation about how to use these functions to solve actual problems, outside of the great syntax docs provided at https://xdebug.org/docs/develop ?

I would start with the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide), and also have a look at the recently rewritten [step debugger documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug). I've also recently starting videos for specific things to the documentation, a few on [step debugging](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#related_content), and there a [full list](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_related_content) as well.

I am still adding to these videos, and will also be adding non-video content.
If you want to suggest specific ideas for these videos, please send in a documentation issue in Xdebug's [bug tracker](https://bugs.xdebug.org/).

Comment: Sincere thanks for your time here @derick, and for this fine software! I missed the upgrade guide. I'm a senior developer with other tech but have never had the time/need to learn/use Xdebug until now. All I know about it comes from recent research, and of course most notes so far are v2-specific. That will change over time. I modified my VSCode workspace settings to ignore paths and the specific files throwing exceptions, but that's not working. I'll take that up with the extension guys. TYVM for issue#1985. Until that's processed, even a procedure or hack would help, when possible.

Comment: Correction to my last comment! (Could not edit) The VSCode extension, settings 'ignore' does work! VSCode does not stop on the exception line - that's what 'ignore' in that extension is supposed to do. But, as expected, Xdebug itself still injects information about an issue into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got VS Code to recognise xdebug functions today: add the 'xdebug' item to the Intelephense: Stubs setting.